# How to create a rewriteMap in IIS with dynamic path?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a rewrite map in IIS to rewrite any call from `domain.com/v/{PATH}` to `domain.com/api/v/{PATH}` as i've changed my hosting logic and as an external service can't change the `.GET` request is making to `domain.com/v/{PATH}` in `domain.com/api/v/{PATH}` i have to rewrite any call in IIS..

I've created the following rewriteMap:

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="vmenuAuth">
            <add key="/v/" value="/api/v/" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Regola di reindirizzamento1 per vmenuAuth">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{vmenuAuth:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it works only if the url has **ONLY** the /v/ so if i write `domain.com/v/` it rewrite the url to `domain.com/api/v/` but if i try to add the path `domain.com/v/VHGbrbfFHHTRfbFKSZ` it will still remain the same without redirecting the user to `domain.com/api/v/VHGbrbfFHHTRfbFKSZ`

Comment: Rewrite maps are for static one-to-one mappings. If you need flexibility on pattern matching, you'd better write your own provider, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Do you only need to do this for anything that matches `domain.com/v/{PATH}` or also a lot of different URLs? If it is limited to `domain.com/v/{PATH}` then you can just use a rule for this and not the `rewriteMaps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is unnecessary to apply the URL `Rewrite Maps` under the circumstance.
We will redirect the URL to the new path as long as we match the “/v/” segment, is it right?
Please refer to the below configuration.

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="abc" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
                        <add input="{Request_URI}" pattern="/v(.*)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/api/v{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="MyMap" defaultValue="">
          <add key="1234" value="HtmlPage1.html"></add>
        </rewriteMap>
      </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: That was it, the only thing i've changed is that the {PATH} after /v/ is always a Base64 string so i've added in the pattern even the regex for Base64 control